# Drupal sometimes doesn't save or delete node

Tags: nodes

I have experienced sometimes after few minutes spent on the edit page (to fill the form), I want to save or delete the node, it doesn't work. It redirect to the edit page without any notification or error message with the previous state of the node. (the modifications are gone) Then I do it again the same steps, same datas and it saves fine.

I have the same issue with creating new node. It's not frequent, pretty random.

Thanks for the helpful advices.

Comment: How often are you running cron, eg a lot?  If you are somehow clearing the form caches outside the drupal norm, this *could* cause behavior like this.

Comment: I run Cron only hourly, so it should not affect on this.